# Are mutex locks necessary when multiple threads access the same variable in this case?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

In C, I am utilizing pthreads in order to perform computations on a shared array across pthreads. Each of the pthreads is distinctly given offsets so that their area of computation has no overlap.

Example:

- Thread 0 updates array[0] thru array[9]
- Thread 1 updates array[10] thru array[19]
- Thread 2 updates array[20] thru array[29]

Are mutex locks still necessary in this case if none of the computation overlaps and they are not reliant on the updates of neighboring indices across thread boundaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, since these accesses are on separate, distinct memory locations, they are not even potentially conflicting, and so they do not require synchronization with respect to one another.

Comment: As long as these are simple arrays. If he's using some fancy vector structure where accessing any element requires accessing(and potentially changing) the vector object itself, things might be more complicated.